# Android isoDep.transceive on Generate AC command always returns 6D00 unsupported

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, emv, contactless-smartcard

I'm trying to emulate a PoS, point of sale :), system and complete a transaction with Google wallet running on a 2013 Nexus 7 (no secure element) v4.4.2.

My PoS prototype is also running on a 2013 Nexus 7 v4.4.2.

I'm able to get NFC responses from the 2PAY_SYS_DDF01 request.
I'm able to select the MasterCard application ID.
I'm able to get Processing Options.
When I Read Records it doesn't look like Google wallet is returning all the mandatory EMV fields.
And finally when I request the Generate AC command it always returns 6D00 unsupported.

Area of the code that is a problem:

```
//set P1 to '40', to request an Transaction Certificate (offline transaction) 
//and execute the Generate AC command.

byte[] generateAC = new byte[] {(byte)0x80, (byte)0xAE, 0x40, 0x00,
                0x1D,                               //data length
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, //amount1
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //amount2
                0x08, 0x40,                         //term country
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       //tvr
                0x09, 0x62,                         //tx curr
                0x14, 0x04, 0x1B,                   //tx date
                0x00,                               //tx type
                0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78,             //random
                0x00};                              //le
response = isoDep.transceive(generateAC);
```

I was following Tim Beckers video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqobg1-HrfY
approx. 46 minutes in.
and Tim Beckers code sample:
https://github.com/a2800276/29c3/blob/master/smartshell.rb

**UPDATE:**

The response to the GPO command (`80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00`) is

```
770a820200009404080101009000

77 Response Message Template Format 2
    82 Application Interchange Profile
        0000
    94 Application File Locator (AFL)
        08010100
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

```
byte[] computeCC = new byte[] {
(byte)0x80, // CLA = proprietary
(byte)0x2A, // INS = COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM
(byte)0x8E, // P1
(byte)0x80, // P2
(byte)0x04, // Lc
(byte)0x00, 0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x99, // Unpredicatable Number (numeric)
(byte)0x00, // Le
};
response = isoDep.transceive(computeCC);
```

hoping to at least get an error that indicated the wrong unpredictable number but I got 6700 incorrect length returned.

Earlier I got a response to Read Record 00 B2 01 0C 00
Part of that response is 
    Card Authentication Related Data [9F69]:
    Data (Binary):  XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
    fDDA Version Number: 9F
    (Card) Unpredictable Number: 6A 04 9F 7E

So I tried that Unpredictable number

```
byte[] computeCC = new byte[] {
(byte)0x80, // CLA = proprietary
(byte)0x2A, // INS = COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM
(byte)0x8E, // P1
(byte)0x80, // P2
(byte)0x04, // Lc
(byte)0x6A, 0x04, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x7E, // Unpredicatable Number (numeric)
(byte)0x00, // Le
};
response = isoDep.transceive(computeCC);
```

But I still get 6700 wrong length

**UPDATE:**

The response to  READ RECORD (Record = 1, SFI = 1) command (00 B2 01 0C 00)
is:

```
70 7c 9f 6c 02
00 01 9f 62 06
00 00 00 00 00
38 9f 63 06 00
00 00 00 03 c6
56 29 42 35 33
39 36 XX XX XX
XX 31 XX XX 39
XX XX XX XX 5e
20 2f 5e 31 34
30 37 31 30 31
34 30 31 30 30
30 30 30 30 30
30 30 30 9f 64
01 04 9f 65 02
00 38 9f 66 02
03 c6 9f 6b 13
53 96 XX XX 1X
X9 XX XX d1 40
71 01 40 10 00
00 00 00 0f 9f
67 01 04 9f 69
0f 9f 6a 04 9f
7e 01 9f 02 06
5f 2a 02 9f 1a
02 90 00

--------------------------TLV------------------------------- 
Output:
READ RECORD Response Message Template [70]:
    Card Transaction Qualifiers (CTQ) [9F6C]:
    Data (Binary):  00 01 
Bit flags set:
    1Bxb8: 0 - Online PIN not Required
    1Bxb7: 0 - Signature Not Required
    1Bxb6: 0 - Not applicable: Go Online if Offline Data Authentication     Fails and Reader is online capable.
    1Bxb5: 0 - Not applicable: Switch Interface if Offline Data     Authentication fails and Reader supports VIS.
    1Bxb4: 0 - Not applicable: Go Online if Application Expired
    1Bxb3: 0 - Not applicable: Switch Interface for Cash Transactions
    1Bxb2: 0 - Not applicable: Switch Interface for Cashback Transactions
    1Bxb1: 0 - RFU
    2Bxb8: 0 - Consumer Device CVM not Performed
    2Bxb7: 0 - Card doesn't support Issuer Update Processing at the POS
    2Bxb6: 0 - RFU
    2Bxb5: 0 - RFU
    2Bxb4: 0 - RFU
    2Bxb3: 0 - RFU
    2Bxb2: 0 - RFU
    2Bxb1: 1 - RFU
PCVC3 (Track1) [9F62]:
    Data (Binary):  00 00 00 00 00 38 
Offline Counter Initial Value [9F63]:
    Data (Binary):  00 00 00 00 03 C6 
Track 1 Data [56]:

    Data (ASCII):   B5396XXXXXXXXXXXX^ /^14071014010000000000
NATC (Track1) [9F64]:
    Data (Binary):  04 
PCVC3 (Track2) [9F65]:
    Data (Binary):  00 38 
Terminal Transaction Qualifiers (TTQ) [9F66]:
    Data (Binary):  03 C6 
Card CVM Limit [9F6B]:
    Data (Binary):  53 96 48 50 17 69 62 32 D1 40 71 01 40 10 00 00 00 00 0F 
MSD Offset [9F67]:
    Data (Binary):  04 
Card Authentication Related Data [9F69]:
    Data (Binary):  9F 6A 04 9F 7E 01 9F 02 06 5F 2A 02 9F 1A 02 
fDDA Version Number: 9F
(Card) Unpredictable Number: 6A 04 9F 7E
Card Transaction Qualifiers: 01 9F
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you post the data you receive in response to the GPO command?

Comment: This is the data sent and received for GPO  
  
send = 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00  
response = 770a820200009404080101009000  


77 Response Message Template Format 2  

  82 Application Interchange Profile  

    0000  
  94 Application File Locator (AFL)  

    08010100

Comment: Can you please post the full response (possibly masking out the card number) that you get for the READ RECORD (Record = 1, SFI = 1) command (`00 B2 01 0C 00`)?

Comment: The way you decoded the file does not make much sense. See my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response to the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command indicates the following Application Interchange Profile (AIP):

```
82 Application Interchange Profile
    0000
```

Google Wallet is basically a MasterCard (EMV contactless kernel 2), so decoding the AIP according to the rules of Kernel 2 results in the following:

```
Byte 1, b7 = 0: no SDA supported
        b6 = 0: no DDA supported
        b5 = 0: no cardholder verification supported
        b4 = 0: no terminal risk management to be performed
        b3 = 0: no issuer authentication supported
        b2 = 0: no on-device cardholder verification supported
        b1 = 0: no CDA supported
Byte 2, b8 = 0: no EMV mode supported
```

The important part is byte 2, bit 8: It indicates that your card does not support EMV mode. Hence, your card/Google Wallet is a PayPass card that supports only Mag-Stripe mode. Therefore, you cannot authenticate transactions using GENERATE AC. Instead, you can only let the card generate dynamic card verification codes (CVC3) using COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM:

```
byte[] computeCC = new byte[] {
    (byte)0x80, // CLA = proprietary
    (byte)0x2A, // INS = COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM
    (byte)0x8E, // P1
    (byte)0x80, // P2
    (byte)0x04, // Lc
    (byte)0xWW, (byte)0xXX, (byte)0xYY, (byte)0xZZ, // Unpredicatable Number (numeric)
    (byte)0x00, // Le
};
response = isoDep.transceive(computeCC);
```

Note that the data field of the COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM command must be filled with values according to the UDOL (in case there is no UDOL, the default UDOL is `9F6A04`, indicating the unpredictable number, numeric).

The unpredictable number (numeric) is a BCD coded number in the range that is defined by the mag-stripe data file (see the AFL). In the past, for Google Wallet, this was a value between 0 and 99 (i.e. `WW='00'`, `XX='00'`, `YY='00'`, `ZZ='00'..'99'`).

**UPDATE:**

The data read from the card decodes as follows:

```
70 7c
  9f6c 02    Mag-stripe application version number = Version 1
    00 01
  9f62 06    Track 1 bit map for CVC3
    00 00 00 00 00 38
  9f63 06    Track 1 bit map for UN and ATC
    00 00 00 00 03 c6
  56 29      Track 1 data
    42         ISO/IEC 7813 structure "B" format
    35333936 XXXXXXXX 31XXXX39 XXXXXXXX    PAN (ASCII)
    5e         Field separator "^"
    202f       Cardholder name " /" (empty, see MC requirements)
    5e         Field separator "^"
    31343037   Expiry date "14"/"07"
    313031     Service code "101"
    34303130303030303030303030    Track 1 discretionary data
  9f64 01    Track 1 number of ATC digits
    04
  9f65 02    Track 2 bit map for CVC3
    00 38
  9f66 02    Track 2 bit map for UN and ATC
    03 c6
  9f6b 13    Track 2 data
    5396 XXXX 1XX9 XXXX    PAN (BCD)
    d          Field separator
    1407       Expiry date
    101        Service code
    4010000000000    Track 2 discretionary data
    f          Padding
  9f67 01      Track 2 number of ATC digits
    04
  9f69 0f      UDOL
    9f6a 04      Unpredictable number (numeric)
    9f7e 01      Mobile support indicator
    9f02 06      Amount authorized (numeric)
    5f2a 02      Transaction currency code
    9f1a 02      Terminal country code
```

So the card **does** provide a UDOL. Therefore, the COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM command has to be adapted accordingly:

```
byte[] computeCC = new byte[] {
    (byte)0x80, // CLA = proprietary
    (byte)0x2A, // INS = COMPUTE CRYPTOGRAPHIC CHECKSUM
    (byte)0x8E, // P1
    (byte)0x80, // P2
    (byte)0x0F, // Lc
    // 9f6a 04      Unpredictable number (numeric)
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x12, // two digits according to UN/ATC bit map and number of ATC digits: 6 - 4 = 2
    // 9f7e 01      Mobile support indicator
    (byte)0x00, // no offline PIN required, no mobile support
    // 9f02 06      Amount authorized (numeric)
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, // 1.00
    // 5f2a 02      Transaction currency code
    (byte)0x09, (byte)0x78, // Euro
    // 9f1a 02      Terminal country code
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x40, // Austria
    (byte)0x00, // Le
};
response = isoDep.transceive(computeCC);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Michael, I'm now getting a valid 90 00 response.

Comment: I get 6982 (Security state not satisfied) when sending this last request (802a8e800f00000012000000000001000840084000) - ideas?

Comment: That seems to have fixed itself (probably pin related), but now I'm confused as to how to take the checksum result and splice it into the track data. Do you have any examples of that? Even just input/output would be gold.