# APDU command to read credit card data from visa Paywave NFC enabled card using Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv

```
  byte[] APDUCommand = { 
            (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class           
            (byte) 0xA4, // INS Instruction     
            (byte) 0x04, // P1  Parameter 1
            (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
            (byte) 0x0A, // Length
            0x63,0x64,0x63,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x32,0x31 // AID
        };


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    IsoDep iso = IsoDep.get(tag);        
    iso.connect();

    byte[] result = iso.transceive(APDUCommand);
```

I am using the above code to read VisaPayWave NFC card details(card holder's name, expiry date, card number etc) using samsung galaxy s4. The output that i am getting is [106,-126]. I think the APDU command i am using is not correct. Kindly suggest the correct command.

Answer (score 2):

Change your APDU command definition

```
byte[] APDUCommand = { 
        (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class           
        (byte) 0xA4, // INS Instruction     
        (byte) 0x04, // P1  Parameter 1
        (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
        (byte) 0x07, // Length
        (byte) 0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x10,0x10 // AID
    };
```

Comment: it is not working. Can anybody please suggest what is it that i am doing wrong. Do i need multiple APDU commands to read all the data? If yes please let me know the algorithm or the code.

Comment: This command is the first step. First you need to select the applet so that then you can read the data.

You need to make sure the applet is activated.

Answer (score 2):

As [lletami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3055270/lletami) answered, Visa payWave is typically selectable with the AID `A0000000031010`. So you can use the APDU

```
00 A4 04 00 07 A0000000031010 00
```

to select the payWave appplication.

On contactless EMV payment cards, you could also select the PPSE (Proximity Payment System Environment) to retrieve a list of available applications (and their AIDs):

```
00 A4 04 00 0E 325041592E5359532E4444463031 00
```

Selecting the EMV payment application is only the first step. You would need to issue several further commands to get the readable credit card data (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113332/2425802)).

For instance, you could issue a GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359247/2425802), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23892530/2425802) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23591064/2425802)).

And/or you could issue READ RECORD commands to get data from known elementary files. E.g.

```
00 B2 01 0C 00
```

to read record 1 of EF 1,

```
00 B2 02 0C 00
```

to read record 2 of EF 1, or

```
00 B2 01 14 00
```

to read record 1 of EF 2, etc.

You can get the EMV specifications for payment systems from http://www.emvco.com/ to learn about possible commands and data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Your response code [106, -126] is better represented as hexadecimal, rather than implying any signed values.

It actually would be 6A82 - which forms SW1 and SW2 of the APDU Response Code. 6A82 corresponds to "Wrong parameter(s) P1 P2; file not found". See EMV Book 1 for more details. I.e. "0x63,0x64,0x63,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x32,0x31" was not found on the card - but "0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x10,0x10" should be.

As lletami says, your APDU command needs rebuilding, including the AID using 'compressed numeric' (as described in EMV Book 1), very similar to Binary Coded Decimal.